# Google Earth Engine Computation timed-out Error

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, performance

I adapted the GEE script from the UN-Spider website, which now returns an computation timed-out error after 12 hours. The script basically calculates the flood extent and then overlays it with landcover data to evaluate which land cover classes have been affected by flooding. The main performance issue is probably the 10 resolution of the landcover image...

I already implemented the "bestEffort" and "tileScale" options into the reduceRegion statements. How can I further improve the code in terms of performance?

```
/*===========================================================================================
                       SAR-FLOOD MAPPING USING A CHANGE DETECTION APPROACH
  ===========================================================================================
  Within this script SAR Sentinel-1 is being used to generate a flood extent map. A change 
  detection approach was chosen, where a before- and after-flood event image will be compared. 
  Sentinel-1 GRD imagery is being used. Ground Range Detected imagery includes the following 
  preprocessing steps: Thermal-Noise Removal, Radiometric calibration, Terrain-correction 
  hence only a Speckle filter needs to be applied in the preprocessing.  
  
  Additionally, the resulting flood extent was overlaid with a Land Use / Land Cover Map to
  calculate the exposure of each class to flooding.
  
  Furthermore, the resulting flood extent was overlaid with population density  to assess the
  number of affected people.
 
  ===========================================================================================

  *******************************************************************************************
                                       SET TIME FRAME

   Set start and end dates of a period BEFORE the flood. Make sure it is long enough for 
   Sentinel-1 to acquire an image (repitition rate = 6 days). Adjust these parameters, if
   your ImageCollections (see Console) do not contain any elements.*/
 
var before_start= '2022-12-30';
var before_end='2023-01-15';

// Now set the same parameters for AFTER the flood.
var after_start='2023-08-09';
var after_end='2023-08-25';


/********************************************************************************************
                           SET SAR PARAMETERS (can be left default)*/

var polarization = "VH"; /*or 'VV' --> VH mostly is the prefered polarization for flood mapping.
                           However, it always depends on your study area, you can select 'VV' 
                           as well.*/ 
var pass_direction = "DESCENDING"; /* or 'ASCENDING'when images are being compared use only one 
                           pass direction. Consider changing this parameter, if your image 
                           collection is empty. In some areas more Ascending images exist than 
                           than descending or the other way around.*/
var difference_threshold = 1.25; /*threshodl to be applied on the difference image (after flood
                           - before flood). It has been chosen by trial and error. In case your
                           flood extent result shows many false-positive or negative signals, 
                           consider changing it! */
//var relative_orbit = 79; 
                          /*if you know the relative orbit for your study area, you can filter
                           you image collection by it here, to avoid errors caused by comparing
                           different relative orbits.*/


/********************************************************************************************
  ---->>> DO NOT EDIT THE SCRIPT PAST THIS POINT! (unless you know what you are doing) <<<---
  ------------------>>> now hit the'RUN' at the top of the script! <<<-----------------------
  -----> The final flood product will be ready for download on the right (under tasks) <-----

  ******************************************************************************************/

//---------------------------------- Translating User Inputs ------------------------------//

//------------------------------- DATA SELECTION & PREPROCESSING --------------------------//

// rename selected geometry feature 
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

// Load and filter Sentinel-1 GRD data by predefined parameters 
var collection= ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode','IW'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', polarization))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass',pass_direction)) 
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters',10))
  //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('relativeOrbitNumber_start',relative_orbit ))
  .filterBounds(aoi)
  .select(polarization);
  
// Select images by predefined dates
var before_collection = collection.filterDate(before_start, before_end);
var after_collection = collection.filterDate(after_start,after_end);

// Print selected tiles to the console

      // Extract date from meta data
      function dates(imgcol){
        var range = imgcol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"]);
        var printed = ee.String('from ')
          .cat(ee.Date(range.get('min')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
          .cat(' to ')
          .cat(ee.Date(range.get('max')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
        return printed;
      }
      // print dates of before images to console
      var before_count = before_collection.size();
      print(ee.String('Tiles selected: Before Flood ').cat('(').cat(before_count).cat(')'),
        dates(before_collection), before_collection);
      
      // print dates of after images to console
      var after_count = before_collection.size();
      print(ee.String('Tiles selected: After Flood ').cat('(').cat(after_count).cat(')'),
        dates(after_collection), after_collection);

// Create a mosaic of selected tiles and clip to study area
var before = before_collection.mosaic().clip(aoi);
var after = after_collection.mosaic().clip(aoi);

// Apply reduce the radar speckle by smoothing  
var smoothing_radius = 50;
var before_filtered = before.focal_mean(smoothing_radius, 'circle', 'meters');
var after_filtered = after.focal_mean(smoothing_radius, 'circle', 'meters');


//------------------------------- FLOOD EXTENT CALCULATION -------------------------------//

// Calculate the difference between the before and after images
var difference = after_filtered.divide(before_filtered);

// Apply the predefined difference-threshold and create the flood extent mask 
var threshold = difference_threshold;
var difference_binary = difference.gt(threshold);

// Refine flood result using additional datasets
      
      // Include JRC layer on surface water seasonality to mask flood pixels from areas
      // of "permanent" water (where there is water > 10 months of the year)
      var swater = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater').select('seasonality');
      var swater_mask = swater.gte(10).updateMask(swater.gte(10));
      
      //Flooded layer where perennial water bodies (water > 10 mo/yr) is assigned a 0 value
      var flooded_mask = difference_binary.where(swater_mask,0);
      // final flooded area without pixels in perennial waterbodies
      var flooded = flooded_mask.updateMask(flooded_mask);
      
      // Compute connectivity of pixels to eliminate those connected to 8 or fewer neighbours
      // This operation reduces noise of the flood extent product 
      var connections = flooded.connectedPixelCount();    
      var flooded = flooded.updateMask(connections.gte(8));
      
      // Mask out areas with more than 5 percent slope using a Digital Elevation Model 
      var DEM = ee.Image('WWF/HydroSHEDS/03VFDEM');
      var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(DEM);
      var slope = terrain.select('slope');
      var flooded = flooded.updateMask(slope.lt(5));
      

// Calculate flood extent area
// Create a raster layer containing the area information of each pixel 
var flood_pixelarea = flooded.select(polarization)
  .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// Sum the areas of flooded pixels
// default is set to 'bestEffort: true' in order to reduce compuation time, for a more 
// accurate result set bestEffort to false and increase 'maxPixels'. 
var flood_stats = flood_pixelarea.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),              
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10, // native resolution 
  maxPixels: 1e9,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });

// Convert the flood extent to hectares (area calculations are originally given in meters)  
var flood_area_ha = flood_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(10000)
  .round(); 

//------------------------------  DAMAGE ASSSESSMENT  ----------------------------------//

//----------------------------- Exposed population density ----------------------------//

// Load JRC Global Human Settlement Popluation Density layer
// Resolution: 100. Number of people per cell is given.
var merged_pop = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages ([pop1, pop2, pop3, pop4]);
//Map.addLayer(merged_extent,{},'merged_extent');

// Convert the image collection to an image using mosaic
var population = merged_pop.mosaic();
var population_count = population.clip(aoi);

// Create a raster showing exposed population only using the resampled flood layer
var population_exposed = population_count
  .updateMask(flooded)
  .updateMask(population_count);

//Sum pixel values of exposed population raster 
var stats = population_exposed.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 100,
  maxPixels:1e9,
  tileScale:16
});

var districts = districts.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Country', 'Lao PDR'));

// Sum pixel values of exposed population raster per district
var stats_district = population_exposed.reduceRegions({
  collection: districts,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 100,
  tileScale:16
});

// get number of exposed people as integer
var number_pp_exposed = stats.getNumber('b1').round();


//----------------------------- Land Use / Land Cover Assessment----------------------------//
// using MRC LULC 2020, 10m
var landcover_projection = landcover.projection();

// filter image collection 
var LC = landcover
  .clip(aoi);

//----------------------------- Affected agricultural land ----------------------------//

// Extract only cropland pixels using the classes cropland
var cropmask = LC
  .eq(1);
var cropland = LC
  .updateMask(cropmask);

// Calculate affected cropland using the resampled flood layer
var cropland_affected = flooded
  .updateMask(cropland);

// sum pixels of affected cropland layer
var crop_stats = cropland_affected.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });
  
// convert area to hectares
var crop_area_ha = crop_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(100)
  .round();

//----------------------------- Affected orchards ----------------------------//

// Extract only orchards pixels using the classes orchards
var orchmask = LC
  .eq(12);
var orchards = LC
  .updateMask(orchmask);

// Calculate affected orchards using the resampled flood layer
var orchards_affected = flooded
  .updateMask(orchards);
  
//Map.addLayer(orchards_affected, urbanVis, 'orchards_affected',0); 


// sum pixels of affected orchards layer
var orchard_stats = orchards_affected.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });
  
// convert area to hectares
var orchard_area_ha = orchard_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(100)
  .round();
  
  //----------------------------- Affected aquacultures ----------------------------//

// Extract only aquaculture pixels
var aquamask = LC
  .eq(2);
var aquaculture = LC
  .updateMask(aquamask);
  
// Calculate affected aquacultures using the resampled flood layer
var aquaculture_affected = flooded
  .updateMask(aquaculture);

// sum pixels of affected aquacultures layer
var aquaculture_stats = aquaculture_affected.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });
  
// convert area to hectares
var aquaculture_area_ha = aquaculture_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(100)
  .round();
  
    //----------------------------- Affected Industrial Plantations ----------------------------//

// Extract only Industrial Plantations pixels
var indmask = LC
  .eq(10);
var ind = LC
  .updateMask(indmask);

// Calculate affected Industrial Plantations using the resampled flood layer
var ind_affected = flooded
  .updateMask(ind);

// sum pixels of affected Industrial Plantations layer
var ind_stats =ind_affected.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });
  
// convert area to hectares
var ind_area_ha = ind_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(100)
  .round();

  
  //----------------------------- Affected rice ----------------------------//

// Extract only rice pixels
var ricemask = LC
  .eq(13);
var rice = LC
  .updateMask(ricemask);

// Calculate affected rice using the resampled flood layer
var rice_affected = flooded
  .updateMask(rice);

// sum pixels of affected rice layer
var rice_stats =rice_affected.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });
  
// convert area to hectares
var rice_area_ha = rice_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(100)
  .round();

//-------------------------------- Affected urban area ------------------------------//

// filter image collection 
var urbanmask = LC.eq(14);
var urban = LC
  .updateMask(urbanmask);
  
  var urban_affected = flooded
  .updateMask(urban);

// sum pixels of affected urban area layer
var urban_stats = urban_affected.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //sum all pixels with area information                
  geometry: aoi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  bestEffort: true,
  tileScale:16
  });
  
// convert area to hectares
var urban_area_ha = urban_stats
  .getNumber(polarization)
  .divide(100)
  .round();
  
//------------------------------  DISPLAY PRODUCTS  ----------------------------------//

// Before and after flood SAR mosaic
Map.centerObject(aoi,8);
Map.addLayer(before_filtered, {min:-25,max:0}, 'Before Flood',0);
Map.addLayer(after_filtered, {min:-25,max:0}, 'After Flood',0);

// Difference layer
Map.addLayer(difference,{min:0,max:2},"Difference Layer",0);

// Flooded areas
Map.addLayer(flooded,{palette:"0000FF"},'Flooded areas',1);

// Population Density
var populationCountVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 200.0,
  palette: ['060606','337663','337663','ffffff'],
};
Map.addLayer(population_count, populationCountVis, 'Population Density',0);

// Exposed Population
var populationExposedVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 200.0,
  palette: ['yellow', 'orange', 'red'],
};
Map.addLayer(population_exposed, populationExposedVis, 'Exposed Population',0);

// Land Cover
var LCVis = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 17.0,
  palette: [
    '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
    'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
    '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff'
  ],
};
Map.addLayer(LC, LCVis, 'Land Cover',0);

// Cropland
var croplandVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 14.0,
  palette: ['30b21c'],
};
Map.addLayer(cropland, croplandVis, 'Cropland',0);

// Affected cropland
Map.addLayer(cropland_affected, croplandVis, 'Affected Cropland',0); 

// Urban
var urbanVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 13.0,
  palette: ['grey'],
};

// Affected urban
Map.addLayer(urban_affected, urbanVis, 'Affected Urban',0); 


//------------------------------------- EXPORTS ------------------------------------//

// Export flooded area as TIFF file 
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: flooded, 
  description: 'lao_flood_extent_raster_'+after_end,
  fileNamePrefix: 'lao_flood_extent_raster_'+after_end,
  region: aoi, 
  maxPixels: 1e12
});

// Export flooded area as shapefile (for further analysis in e.g. QGIS)
// Convert flood raster to polygons
var flooded_vec = flooded.reduceToVectors({
  scale: 10,
  geometryType:'polygon',
  geometry: aoi,
  eightConnected: false,
  bestEffort:true,
  tileScale:10,
});

// Export flood polygons as shape-file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:flooded_vec,
  description:'lao_flood_extent_vector_'+after_end,
  fileFormat:'SHP',
  fileNamePrefix:'lao_flood_extent_vector_'+after_end
});

// Exposed population density raster
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:population_exposed,
  description:'lao_exposed_population_raster_'+after_end,
  scale: 100,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  fileNamePrefix:'lao_population_exposed_raster_'+after_end,
  region: aoi,
  maxPixels:1e10
});

// Create a feature collection from variables
var stats = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, {after_start:after_start,after_end:after_end,flood_area_ha:flood_area_ha,number_pp_exposed:number_pp_exposed, urban_area_ha:urban_area_ha,crop_area_ha:crop_area_ha,aquaculture_area_ha:aquaculture_area_ha,rice_area_ha:rice_area_ha,orchard_area_ha:orchard_area_ha,ind_area_ha:ind_area_ha}),
  // Add more features for other variables as needed
]);

// Statistics on country level as table
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:stats,
  description:'lao_stats_all_'+after_end,
  fileFormat:'CSV',
  fileNamePrefix:'lao_stats_all_'+after_end
});


var stats_district_col = stats_district.select(['Country', 'District', 'Province','sum']); //


// Export number_ppl_exposed on district level
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:stats_district_col,
  description:'lao_population_stats_district_'+after_end,
  selectors:['Country', 'District', 'Province','sum'],
  fileFormat:'CSV',
  fileNamePrefix:'lao_population_stats_district_'+after_end
});



//---------------------------------- MAP PRODUCTION --------------------------------//

//-------------------------- Display the results on the map -----------------------//

// set position of panel where the results will be displayed 
var results = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 15px',
    width: '350px'
  }
});

//Prepare the visualtization parameters of the labels 
var textVis = {
  'margin':'0px 8px 2px 0px',
  'fontWeight':'bold'
  };
var numberVIS = {
  'margin':'0px 0px 15px 0px', 
  'color':'bf0f19',
  'fontWeight':'bold'
  };
var subTextVis = {
  'margin':'0px 0px 2px 0px',
  'fontSize':'12px',
  'color':'grey'
  };

var titleTextVis = {
  'margin':'0px 0px 15px 0px',
  'fontSize': '18px', 
  'font-weight':'', 
  'color': '3333ff'
  };

// Create lables of the results 
// Titel and time period
var title = ui.Label('Results', titleTextVis);
var text1 = ui.Label('Flood status between:',textVis);
var number1 = ui.Label(after_start.concat(" and ",after_end),numberVIS);

// Alternatively, print dates of the selected tiles
//var number1 = ui.Label('Please wait...',numberVIS); 
//(after_collection).evaluate(function(val){number1.setValue(val)}),numberVIS;

// Estimated flood extent 
var text2 = ui.Label('Estimated flood extent:',textVis);
var text2_2 = ui.Label('Please wait...',subTextVis);
dates(after_collection).evaluate(function(val){text2_2.setValue('based on Senintel-1 imagery '+val)});
var number2 = ui.Label('Please wait...',numberVIS); 
flood_area_ha.evaluate(function(val){number2.setValue(val+' hectares')}),numberVIS;

// Estimated number of exposed people
var text3 = ui.Label('Estimated number of exposed people: ',textVis);
var text3_2 = ui.Label('based on GHSL 2020 (100m)',subTextVis);
var number3 = ui.Label('Please wait...',numberVIS);
number_pp_exposed.evaluate(function(val){number3.setValue(val)}),numberVIS;

// Estimated area of affected cropland 
var MODIS_date = ee.String(LC.get('system:index')).slice(0,4);
var text4 = ui.Label('Estimated affected cropland:',textVis);
var text4_2 = ui.Label('Please wait', subTextVis);
MODIS_date.evaluate(function(val){text4_2.setValue('based on MRC Land Cover (10m)')}), subTextVis;
var number4 = ui.Label('Please wait...',numberVIS);
crop_area_ha.evaluate(function(val){number4.setValue(val+' hectares')}),numberVIS;

// Estimated area of affected urban
var text5 = ui.Label('Estimated affected urban areas:',textVis);
var text5_2 = ui.Label('Please wait', subTextVis);
MODIS_date.evaluate(function(val){text5_2.setValue('based on MRC Land Cover (10m)')}), subTextVis;
var number5 = ui.Label('Please wait...',numberVIS);
urban_area_ha.evaluate(function(val){number5.setValue(val+' hectares')}),numberVIS;

// Disclaimer
var text6 = ui.Label('Disclaimer: This product has been derived automatically without validation data. All geographic information has limitations due to the scale, resolution, date and interpretation of the original source materials. No liability concerning the content or the use thereof is assumed by the producer.',subTextVis);

// Produced by...
var text7 = ui.Label('Script produced by: UN-SPIDER December 2019 and adapted by Vincent Hischier', subTextVis);

// Add the labels to the panel 
results.add(ui.Panel([
        title,
        text1,
        number1,
        text2,
        text2_2,
        number2,
        text3,
        text3_2,
        number3,
        text4,
        text4_2,
        number4,
        text5,
        text5_2,
        number5,
        text6,
        text7]
      ));

// Add the panel to the map 
Map.add(results);

//----------------------------- Display legend on the map --------------------------//

// Create legend (*credits to thisearthsite on Open Geo Blog: https://mygeoblog.com/2016/12/09/add-a-legend-to-to-your-gee-map/)
// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-right',
    padding: '8px 15px',
  }
});
 
// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label('Legend',titleTextVis);
 
// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);
 
// Creates and styles 1 row of the legend.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
 
      // Create the label that is actually the colored box.
      var colorBox = ui.Label({
        style: {
          backgroundColor: color,
          // Use padding to give the box height and width.
          padding: '8px',
          margin: '0 0 4px 0'
        }
      });
 
      // Create the label filled with the description text.
      var description = ui.Label({
        value: name,
        style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
      });
 
      // return the panel
      return ui.Panel({
        widgets: [colorBox, description],
        layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
      });
};
 
//  Palette with the colors
var palette =['#0000FF', '#30b21c', 'grey'];
 
// name of the legend
var names = ['potentially flooded areas','affected cropland','affected urban'];
 
// Add color and and names
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  legend.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }  

// Create second legend title to display exposed population density
var legendTitle2 = ui.Label({
value: 'Exposed population density',
style: {
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '15px',
margin: '10px 0 0 0',
padding: '0'
}
});

// Add second title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle2);

// create the legend image
var lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');
var gradient = lon.multiply((populationExposedVis.max-populationExposedVis.min)/100.0).add(populationExposedVis.min);
var legendImage = gradient.visualize(populationExposedVis);
 
// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label('> '.concat(populationExposedVis['max']))
],
});
 
legend.add(panel);
 
// create thumbnail from the image
var thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
image: legendImage,
params: {bbox:'0,0,10,100', dimensions:'10x50'},
style: {padding: '1px', position: 'bottom-center'}
});
 
// add the thumbnail to the legend
legend.add(thumbnail);
 
// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(populationExposedVis['min'])
],
});
 
legend.add(panel);
 
// add legend to map (alternatively you can also print the legend to the console)
Map.add(legend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. The set values for the "maxPixels" parameter of the "reduceRegion" statement resulted in the computation time-out. I removed the parameter for most of the layers and only kept it for the population layer, where I encountered an error if not setting it. Also, I set the maxPixels value as low as possible. Now the computation only takes a few seconds.